# Arduino MOSFET problems

Tags: arduino, led, mosfet

I'm having difficulties getting this circuit with a MOSFET (BS170) to work.

[image]

I have it set up so that the PIN2 of Arduino (green wire) goes HIGH for 500ms, then LOW for 500ms. This should turn the LED ON for half a second, then turn it OFF for half a second.

Unfortunately it does not work: the LED stays ON and instead of turning OFF, gets slighty dimmer for 500ms, then back to full brightness for 500ms (it's hard to see, but visible if it's dark enough).

While measuring around with a multimeter, I found that if I measure the voltage between ground and PIN2 of the Arduino, the circuit starts working as intended. Here's a video of that in action: https://vimeo.com/481178290.

Shorting the same pins with tweezers just turns the LED off...

What could be causing this malfunction and how do I fix it?

Code:

[image]

Circuit:

[image]

Answered:
It was a fault in code, PIN2 was supposed to be set as OUTPUT

Comment: Edit the question, post the schematic using built-in schematic editor. Breadboard connections are unrecognisable.

Comment: Can you add the circuit?

Comment: Also, check https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531440/arduino-mosfet-control?rq=1 It shows up in the related questions. Did you skim through those?

Comment: Uh wait, that's your question.. Voting to close

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arduino Mosfet control](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/531440/arduino-mosfet-control)

Comment: Post the code. Maybe the code is wrong. Also it looks like there is no resistor for the LED so you are aware that the LED can already be damaged? Or the FET may be damaged. Or Arduino output pin.

Comment: There is no currents limiting resistor in series with LED.

Comment: If you want help add a schematic and show the code. Although the quality photo is good, this is not a correct way of submitting a question here.

Comment: Yes, you have to change the pinMode to OUTPUT instead. Why are you ever set it to INPUT if you are actually "writing" to it? Don't forget to add a LED series resistor. See my complete answer.

Comment: Not a fan of downvotes but yea -1 for reposting the duplicate and wasting the community's time.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this website. Thought that if I update the previous post it will get no attention. Should I delete this post or the previous one?

Comment: You are not right. If you update the question, it will pop up as "active" in the feed. So yea, you will get the attention.

Comment: Try to go easier on users @MituRaj, particularly new users.

Comment: @DeMichaelInigo - Welcome :-) You said: "*Should I delete this post or the previous one?*" FYI you can't delete either question now, since both have got upvoted answers. We can vote to close this one as a duplicate of your first one, and get it closed that way. I recommend you look in the [help] and, as previously commented, [this page](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers) says that editing an answer will "bump it" so that it gets attention. Editing questions to improve  them is part of the Stack Exchange "philosophy". Please don't post duplicates. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I "vote" for the code error in first place. Did you forgot to set pinMode to OUTPUT? Seems like you are doing digitalWrite when pin are configured as INPUT resulting in switching between HIGH state via pull-up enable and Hi-Z state which causes a dim light and/or unstable state when not touched by probe.

Also you better add a resistor in series with LED to limit it's current or you might burn it or MOSFET without it. Resistor value should be calculated by the Ohm law as usual to limit the current through the mosfet. For a 1.8V red LED with 10 mA current this will be (5-1.8)/0.01 = 320 Ohm, leaving a closest value of 330 Ohm to pick.

EDIT: After OP updated the question and added a code screenshot it's clearly seen that MCU pin mode are set to INPUT which causes this issue as noted in 1st paragraph of my answer. Just change the pin mode to OUTPUT instead, add the resistor in series with LED and it will work.

Answer (score -1):

After viewing code it's an issue with code as Nstorm said.

and one more thing after seeing your circuit image you are using the wrong pin as drain and source.

As per datasheet

[image: pinout]

And it would be better if you use two resistors in your circuit it will limit the gate current and will protect your load from false triggering.

adding a small value resistor like 330E between the Mosfet gate and digital pin and one high value like 10K between gate and source pin.

Also to be sure your source pin is used as a ground.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail? I added a 330ohm resistor in place of the green wire (MOSFET gate to PIN2 of Arduino). Where do I place the 10K ohm resistor?

Comment: between Mosfet gate pin and source pin of BS170, it will be 3 pin.

Comment: While generally adding a series resistance on between the MCU pin & gate to limit current usually required to protect a uC pin and adding a pull-up/pull-down resistor to avoid spontaneous switching on the MOSFET from noise when the gate aren't driven by uC logic are usually a good ides this doesn't answers the issue as seen on OP video.